# Eclipse Php : variable undefined evenif it is defined in an require_once php file

Tags: php, eclipse, undefined, require-once

I am using as a beginner :
**Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers**
Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)
Build id: 20180619-1200
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 1.8.0_77

I have a file index.php with a `require_once`(initialisation.php)
The initialisation.php defines a variable $Modeles_Chemin
And the variable $Modeles_Chemin is used in index.php (after the `require_once`)

On my website, it works fine *no undefined variable* but in eclipse editor I receive an *undefined variable*.

(Of course I have the same problem with the other variables).

Here is an extract :
**index.php :**

```
<?php
require_once("prog/php/initialisation_site.php");
include($Modeles_Chemin.$Modeles_Nom."/html_begin.php");
```

**initialisation_site.php** :

```
        $Contenu_Chemin = "contenu/";
$Modeles_Chemin = $Contenu_Chemin."modeles/";
```

How can I fix this ?

thanks

Comment: In the same file "initialisation_site.php" I have string variables and class objects. Eclipse can "see" the class but not the string variables. Why ????

Comment: Related: bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538418

Comment: `$Modeles_Nom`: Where is this variable defined?

Comment: It looks like `$Modeles_Nom` is he undefined a. Pretty obvious actually!

Comment: @delboy1978uk I know that he made a mistake to place that undefined variable there but the problem is about Eclipse PHP Variable Validator ignores include and require.

Comment: The point is STILL that «PHP Variable Validator ignores include and require», as @ICE said.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `global`:

```
require_once("prog/php/initialisation_site.php");

global $Modeles_Chemin;
global $Modeles_Nom;

include($Modeles_Chemin.$Modeles_Nom."/html_begin.php");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get rid of these warnings you may consider putting this kind of comment on the top of the file:

/** @var Type $variable */

This is a workaround but I find it to be a good approach.
This kind of a comment is letting me know that I am using a variable that is defined in a different file.

Comment: This is also useful when a file is included somewhere else, and the variable is defined before the include.

Comment: I am using the CodeIgniter MVC framework, and this Eclipse "undefined" warning comes up everywhere. I tried GLOBAL, which worked in some places but caused issues in others. This @var solution worked in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

This probably means that Eclipse does not understand that those variables are defined in the file that you import with `require_once`.

Maybe it is possible to switch the annotation for undefined variables off in the Eclipse settings? But then you'd also not see warnings for other undefined variables.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than any solution.

Comment: That means that all my PHP includes or requires will not be seen as part of the php file where they included ? I am sure Eclipse can do better